# Django: Send posted files to a different form

Tags: django, forms

Well, I have to send files posted by one form to other form, I have to read an XML file first, if the file is valid I'll redirect to the next form, which has to have the valid file received in the past form. I tried with sessions but I'm not sure if it's the right way to go, here my models.

```
class InitialForm(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    xml = models.FieldField(label='Please choose an XML file')
    ...


class SecondForm(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pdf = models.FieldField(label='Please choose a PDF file')
    ...
```

The reason I got two forms is because I've got to read the XML first and validate it, and then in the next form 'SecondForm' show the data I just parse from the XML in order to verify and give feedback to the user. Then both files must be inserted in a database, only if the first one is valid.

Any help will be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) that Django offers for situations when you need to build a form that is split into multiple requests.

From their docs this is how it works:

> The user visits the first page of the wizard, fills in the form and
>   submits it.
>
> The server validates the data. If it’s invalid, the form
>   is displayed again, with error messages. If it’s valid, the server
>   saves the current state of the wizard in the backend and redirects to
>   the next step.
>
> Step 1 and 2 repeat, for every subsequent form in the
>   wizard.
>
> Once the user has submitted all the forms and all the data has
>   been validated, the wizard processes the data – saving it to the
>   database, sending an email, or whatever the application needs to do.

Comment: I think I'll use form wizards, it is possible to get data from previous forms in the current form through form wizard? I mean a file from a previous form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure it is. That's the purpose of the wizard after all...to maintain data from one request to the other.